# Can not Select Row in my Grid

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, telerik

I do not know for what specific reason i can not select any row from my telerik radGrid.

```
telerik:RadGrid ID="radGridCloseCard" runat="server"
                                AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowSorting="True"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowMultiRowSelection="True"
                                CssClass="radGridClsWizard"
                                OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid_OnNeedDataSource"
                                OnItemDataBound="RadGrid_ItemDataBound">

                                <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />

                                <ClientSettings>
                                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="true"></Scrolling>
                                </ClientSettings>
```

and then the code continues with the bound of the columns and the closing tag of the grid. 
But for me is not possible to select a row and then continue with other methods. Any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by selecting a row? You mean clicking on it, or selecting a row using JavaScript selector?

Comment: @Hooman selecting it by clicking on, and than continue with the next step of my wizard

Comment: not sure, you don't have any JS error when you open the dev tools?

Comment: @Hooman no i dont think so, other grids in the same application work fine

Comment: I know this is almost five years old, but I'm having the same issue. I temporarily got it to work by adding ```ClientSettings-EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true"```, but then it inexplicably broke again with no edits I'm aware of, just copying to elsewhere in the code.